# horizontal centering a base64 background-image does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center that base64 background-image inside an horizontal rectangle div, and it just does not work.

I know it should be pretty trivial and I looked into many almost similar questions here, but no trick worked. The image is not centered horizontally and i do not know why.
In fact, background-position does not seem to take any effect unless I use pixels explicitly.

you can see it in this playground:
https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-worker-vvrx4?file=/index.html

```
.container {
   background: red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 16px;
   background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,...");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}


<div class="container"></div>
```

Could somebody please help?
Thank you.

Comment: you are specifying a background size.

Comment: If I don't then I don't see an image at all. Let me ask you this: shouldn't 100% 100% handle the centering also? why is it to to far to the right?

Comment: By the way, it does not change anything even if I set the background-size to 50% 50%. Still the image is too far to the right and not centered. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not CSS but the SVG image inside the base64 string. When you open it, you find the following code:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve" transform="rotate(90 8 8)" fill="#9c9c9c">
<g>
    <circle cx="7.8" cy="13.9" r="1.7"/>
    <path d="M7.8,11.8c1.2,0,2.1,0.9,2.1,2.1C9.9,15.1,9,16,7.8,16s-2.1-0.9-2.1-2.1C5.7,12.7,6.7,11.8,7.8,11.8z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle cx="7.8" cy="7.9" r="1.7"/>
    <path d="M7.8,5.8c1.2,0,2.1,0.9,2.1,2.1C9.9,9.1,9,10,7.8,10S5.7,9.1,5.7,7.9C5.7,6.8,6.7,5.8,7.8,5.8z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle cx="7.8" cy="2.1" r="1.7"/>
    <path d="M7.8,0C9,0,9.9,0.9,9.9,2.1c0,1.2-0.9,2.1-2.1,2.1S5.7,3.3,5.7,2.1C5.7,0.9,6.7,0,7.8,0z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Notice the `transform="rotation(90 8 8)"` attribute. It rotates the image by 90 degrees around the point [8,8]. The point should be the center of the image according to `viewBox="0 0 16 16"` but for some reason, the dimensions get broken, and an offset of 16 pixels is allocated on the left side of the image.

The simplest fix is to change the value of the transform attribute to `rotation(90)`. The fixed image in base64 is:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is with your SVG. Made a fell changes on it and generated a new base64 that worked fine. I'm not so sure why this solved, though.

**What I did:**

- Changed `transform="rotate(90 8 8)"` to `transform="rotate(90)"`
- Added specific width and height properties `width="160"` `height="160"`

Heres the result

```css
.icon {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 16px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.icon--broken {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}

.icon--fixed {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPCEtLSBHZW5lcmF0b3I6IEFkb2JlIElsbHVzdHJhdG9yIDIxLjAuMiwgU1ZHIEV4cG9ydCBQbHVnLUluIC4gU1ZHIFZlcnNpb246IDYuMDAgQnVpbGQgMCkgIC0tPgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgaWQ9IkxheWVyXzEiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTYgMTYiIHN0eWxlPSJlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZDpuZXcgMCAwIDE2IDE2OyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoOTApIiBmaWxsPSIjMzM5OWZmIiB3aWR0aD0iMTYwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjE2MCI+CjxnPgoJPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNy44IiBjeT0iMTMuOSIgcj0iMS43Ii8+Cgk8cGF0aCBkPSJNNy44LDExLjhjMS4yLDAsMi4xLDAuOSwyLjEsMi4xQzkuOSwxNS4xLDksMTYsNy44LDE2cy0yLjEtMC45LTIuMS0yLjFDNS43LDEyLjcsNi43LDExLjgsNy44LDExLjh6Ii8+CjwvZz4KPGc+Cgk8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI3LjgiIGN5PSI3LjkiIHI9IjEuNyIvPgoJPHBhdGggZD0iTTcuOCw1LjhjMS4yLDAsMi4xLDAuOSwyLjEsMi4xQzkuOSw5LjEsOSwxMCw3LjgsMTBTNS43LDkuMSw1LjcsNy45QzUuNyw2LjgsNi43LDUuOCw3LjgsNS44eiIvPgo8L2c+CjxnPgoJPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNy44IiBjeT0iMi4xIiByPSIxLjciLz4KCTxwYXRoIGQ9Ik03LjgsMEM5LDAsOS45LDAuOSw5LjksMi4xYzAsMS4yLTAuOSwyLjEtMi4xLDIuMVM1LjcsMy4zLDUuNywyLjFDNS43LDAuOSw2LjcsMCw3LjgsMHoiLz4KPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K");
}
```

```html
<div class="icon icon--broken"></div>
<div class="icon icon--fixed"></div>
```

Comment: Yes... I just assumed the svg was aligned.. :( Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the width of the container.

You can see it in this playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-monad-lwqlk?file=/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please notice that it's not centered in your PG either. The hight for my container must be 16px. The width can vary. but I have to ask: why would increasing the width matter? At the end of the day, it's an svg, no?

Comment: I would guess that the issue is with the base64 image itself.